# What are the relevant ratios for converting to square ratio

Tags: resize, image-format, crop

I'm building an application that collects images and convert them to a square ratio images for usage as avatars in social networks.

I want to understand what is the range of image ratios that I can work with and be assured that the image will look OK when I convert its ratio.

For example if I'll take a very wide image and not high enough, if I'll convert it to a square ratio, I'll have to shorten the width and then I'll have too much space above and under the image.

**So is there a rule of thumb regarding what is the max ratio I can use before it'll look bad when converting to square?**

Comment: Converting a non-square to a square format by adding a margin is never looking good. You need to crop the image. Automatic cropping is a problem. Haven't tried this myself yet, but maybe something like this technique would work better for you: https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess that there are some sort of ratios that will work automatically without cropping. saying every ratio that is +-20% 1/1 will look OK when converting to square, I mean - it may have white space on the sides but can work. What do you think? Is there any rule of thumb for that? From your experience?

Comment: As I wrote, I wouldn't do it at all. I'd crop them, if necessary with the help of the user or face recognition or by hand.